# How to plot a graph of y=max⁡{g(x),x}

Tags: r, function, plot, graph, max

I'm new to R programming and I've encountered a math problem which I'm clueless to do in R.

[image: Function]

The question asked to plot the graph of `y=max⁡{g(x),0.5x}` for 10001 values of `x` between (and including) -10 and 10

This is what I've tried so far from t.f example:

```
first.func <- function(x) { 
if (x < 0){
return(x)
}

else if (x = 0){
return(0)
}

else
return(x)
}

second.func <- function(x) {
return(max(first.func(x), x * sin(1/x)))
}

x <- seq(-10, 10, length=10001)

y <- sapply(0.5 * x, second.func)

plot(y ~ x, type = 'l')
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?  You can construct a solution using the `curve()`, `pmax()`, `ifelse()` and `sin()` functions ...

Answer (score 1):

You begin by defining the functions you need. After you have them you can combine them and find the y value. Ill show a different example since it seems like a HW question.

```
first.func <- function(x) { 
  if (x > 3) { 
    return(4)
  }
  if (x <= 3) { 
    return(5 * x)
  }
}

second.func <- function(x) {
  return(min(first.func(x), 3 * x^3))
}

x <- seq(-1, 4, 0.05)

y <- sapply(x, second.func)

plot(y ~ x, type = 'l')
```

[image]

Comment: It’s considered bad form to solve other people’s homework.

Comment: I intentionally didn’t solve the problem he had. Furthermore, I am not sure if it’s a HW question. If it’s still in bad form I don’t mind having it removed.

Comment: Never mind, I hadn’t read properly (my bad!). Your answer is actually a good example of how to deal with such questions.

Comment: thank you for the example. It helps me to kickstart solving it